# Create a folder using FtpWebReqest without using 2 queries or exception flow control

Tags: c#, exception, ftpwebrequest

I have this function to make a directory on a remote server using ftp, however the only two ways I see to do it is either make two FtpWebRequests (one to check to see if the dir exitsts one to create it), or catch the exception when the creation fails.

```
var address = new Uri(String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}/{2}",
    Properties.Settings.Default.Address, 
    arg.RemoteServer.Replace('\\', '_'), 
    ClinicFolder(arg))); //ClinicFolder(arg) is the directory that may or may not exists.
FtpWebRequest request;
request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(address);
request.Credentials = MyCreds
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = keepAlive;
request.Proxy = null;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
try
{
    request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Message != "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).")
        throw;
}
```

I feel like taking a shower ever time I look at what I wrote, but it would take a lot more code to do a dir listing and parse it (and I think more time, but I have not profiled).

Is this the rare case where exception flow control is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch this exception, as another FTP user could create the dir between your check and attempt to create.

Most clients don't seem to enumerate dirs just to check if you can create one; they use an already cached list of dirs, and catch the error.